# Sequence of polygons converging

Tags: geometry, reference-request, polygons, reference-works

Let $P$ be a polygon ($P$ doesn't have to be regular, convex... it's just $n$ distinct points of $\mathbb{R}^2$). We construct the sequence $(P^{(n)})_n$ with $P^{(0)}=P$ and $P^{(n+1)}$ is the polygon obtained the following way : we consider the points cutting all the sides of $P^{(n)}$ in half, $P^{(n+1)}$ is the polygon with these points as vertices. Formally :
$$P^{(0)}=(x_1,\dots , x_n)\in \mathbb{C}^n$$
$$ P^{(n+1)}=\left( \dfrac{x_1^{(k)}+x_2^{(k)}}{2},\dots , \dfrac{x_{n-1}^{(k)}+x_n^{(k)}}{2}, \dfrac{x_n^{(k)}+x_1^{(k)}}{2}\right) .$$

I proved that $(P^{(n)})_n$ converges to the barycenter of $P^{(0)}$ (using algebraic arguments).

I really want to learn more around this result but I can't find anything either in books that I know nor in the internet. For example a question that I would like to have an answer to is the speed of the convergence. Does this result have a name?

> So if you know a book or a pdf file that studies this problem, it would be very nice of you to let me know. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Nice discovery. It's not new, but that doesn't detract from your figuring it out. I don't know a reference. I hope someone does.

Comment: For large $n$, the convergence is _very_ slow. For example, if $n=8$, it takes $77$ iterations for the coefficients of the convex combination to be within $.001$ of $1/8$.

Comment: See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/51008/limit-of-a-sequence-of-polygons.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2080771/midpoint-polygons/2081060#2081060

Answer (score 2):

I first saw that construction in the book [The Mathematical Experience](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mathematical_Experience) and it was a wonderful surprise. See also the classic book [Circulant Matrices](https://bookstore.ams.org/chel-338/) by Philip J. Davis, one of the authors.

See a detailed analysis in this paper:

> Adam N. Elmachtoub and Charles F. Van Loan, [From Random Polygon to Ellipse: An Eigenanalysis](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/090746707), *SIAM Review* 52 (2010) #1, pp. 151-170

Comment: Thank you ! It seems to be a very interesting paper.