# Is this converse results of Varignon's theorem known?

Tags: reference-request, plane-geometry, polygons, quadrilateral, reflection

The [Varignon's Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varignon%27s_theorem)  on *Quadrilateral* is very well known results of Plane Geometry and we have find the *Converse* of this theorem on *Quadrilateral* and generalise this for *2n-sided convex irregular polygon* and *Wanted to know about refrence, article , website where these given below results are mentioned* so that we could verify whether this is *known or not* .

Result 01: *Converse of Varignon Theorem on Quadrilateral* :

Let $A_1A_2A_3A_4$ be parallelogram and Let $B_1$ be arbitrary point and reflect $B_1$ in $A_1$ to get $B_2$ and reflect $B_2$ in $A_2$ to get $B_3$ and Simillary reflect $B_3$ in $A_3$ to get $B_4$ then point { $A_4, B_4, B_1$} become *Straight line* where $A_4$ is midpoint of $B_1B_4$ as Shown in Figure given below: [image: Figure for result 01]

*Note* : Sinc Varignon theorem said that midpoint of Line segment of Quadrilateral makes Parallelogram so will take the midpoint of each Line segment of *2n sided convex polygon as discussed in Result 02 given below*.

*Result 02 (Generalisation of Converse of Varignon theorem)* :

Let $A_1A_2A_3.......A_2n$ be $2n$ sided convex irregular polygon and Let {$B_1, B_2,B_3,......, B_2n$} be m($A_1, A_2$) ; m($A_2, A_3$) ;m($A_3, A_4$) ;m($A_4, A_5$) ;.......... ;m($A_2n, A_1$).

Let $C_1$ be arbitrary Point anywhere in Geometry plane and

reflect $C_1$ in $B_1$ to get $C_2$;

reflect $C_2$ in $B_2$ to get $C_3$;

reflect $C_3$ in $B_3$ to get $C_4$;

Reflect $C_4$ in $B_4$ to get $C_5$
and Simillary defined {$C_6,C_7, C_8,C_9,...., C_2n$ } cyclically then point {$C_2n, B_2n, C_1$} will become Straight line and $B_2n$ become m($C_2n, C_1$).

*See figure for $n=4$:
[image: Varignon theorem]

Note:

(1) Here symbol m(A, B) denotes midpoint of Line Segment AB.

(2)point $A_1, A_2,........, A_2n$ are arbitrary Point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the general case, segments $\,A_1A_2\,$ and $\,C_1C_2\,$ have the same midpoint $\,B_1\,$, so $\,A_1C_2A_2C_1\,$ is a parallelogram and therefore $\,\overrightarrow{A_1C_1}=-\overrightarrow{A_2C_2}\,$. Repeating the argument for the next pairs:

$$
\overrightarrow{A_1C_1}=-\overrightarrow{A_2C_2}=\overrightarrow{A_3C_3}=-\overrightarrow{A_4C_4}=\dots=-\overrightarrow{A_{2n}C_{2n}}
$$

$\overrightarrow{A_1C_1}=-\overrightarrow{A_{2n}C_{2n}}$ means that $A_{2n}C_{2n}A_1C_1$ is a parallelogram, so the diagonals $\,A_{2n}A_1\,$ and $\,C_{2n}C_1\,$ have the same midpoint, in other words $\,C_{2n}\,$ and $\,C_1\,$ are symmetric about $\,B_{2n}\,$.

The property holds true for any $\,2n\,$ points $\,A_1, A_2, \dots, A_{2n}\,$, not necessarily forming a convex polygon, and not necessarily even in the same plane.

Don't know that this property has a name (and it's not a direct converse of Varignon's theorem either), but related questions have been asked before, for example [Midpoint polygons?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2080771/midpoint-polygons).

Comment: Yes, I see the link of midpoint polygon, where this is also discussed on any N sided gon not necessarily even. But i am confused about why this property is not called as converse because if we write the result 01 as " When point $A_4, B_4, B_1$ only become straight line if and only if $A_1A_2A_3A_4$ is parallelogram.      In Varignon theorem we going from quadrilateral to parallelogram and in results 01 , we are going from parallelogram to quadrilateral $B_1B_2B_3B_4$ in results 01.

Comment: @JayendraJha22 What was asked in the question and is proved here is the proposition: "*if $B_1B_2\dots B_{2n}$ is the [midpoint polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_polygon) of a polygon $A_1A_2\dots A_{2n}$ then it is the midpoint polygon of infinitely many polygons $C_1C_2\dots C_{2n}$ where $C_1$ is an arbitrarily chosen point*". That's obviously related to Varignon's construction and theorem, but it's not a direct converse in the logical sense.

Comment: Thanks for clarification .

Answer (score 0):

This is known that the midpoint of segment of polygon is varignon polygon as shown in [this reference](https://en.formulasearchengine.com/wiki/Varignon%27s_theorem) but *the converse result could be new as I don't able to find it anywhere*.

Also see the Extension of Varignon theorem [here](https://ggijro2.files.wordpress.com/2014/04/art531.pdf) and
Also see it's other generalisation on *2n* sided polygon [here](http://frink.machighway.com/%7Edynamicm/octagoncentroids.html)

Note: for more extension , you can see the reference mention in these two above link.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Ok , I have add some extra information with second edit.